# Creating Relationship between a lead and sales literature in Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales, dynamics-crm-sdk

I just got a requirement for asp.net webforms app, which has to integrate with MS Dynamics 365 CRM. I have never done dev for Dynamics 365 but anyhow I've managed to connect with CRM using .net sdk and created a Lead and Sales Literature entity. My intent is to achieve what we can do by going to `Dynamics 365 portal --> Lead --> related --> Activities--> Sales Literature`:

[image]

So, I want to establish relationship between these two entities (lead and sales literature) using .net sdk, here is my code:

```
 AssociateRequest association = new AssociateRequest

            {

                Target = new EntityReference(leadEntity.LogicalName, leadid),

                RelatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection

                {


                 new EntityReference(SLEntity.LogicalName, SLID)
                },

                Relationship = new Relationship("Lead_SalesLiterature"),
                RequestId = new Guid()
            };

           // Execute the request.

           CRMService.Execute(association);
```

But the code fails to establish the relationship on `CRMService.Execute(association);` saying that:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'The Entity Relationship with
>   SchemaName = 'SalesLiterature_Lead' was not found in the
>   MetadataCache'

I have checked both [Lead Entity Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/lead#BKMK_RelatedObjectId) and [Sales Literature Entity Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/salesliterature#BKMK_processstage_salesliteratures) but not finding Schema name for this relationship. Am I missing something or this is not possible?

Comment: Did you verify this?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that the "Sales Literature" showed in your screenshot is a custom activity entity, and it's not the same as OOB "Sales Literature" entity.

To create a custom entity (activity) with a Lead as `regardingobjectid` can be done using this code. Just replace the `task` with your entity name

```
           Entity followup = new Entity("task");
           followup["subject"] = "Sample task - an activity";
           followup["description"] = "Sample description";

           followup["scheduledstart"] = DateTime.Now;
           followup["scheduledend"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

           Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid("26ADDD07-D9F4-E711-8138-E0071B715B11"); //leadid
           string regardingobjectidType = "lead";
           followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(regadingobjectidType,regardingobjectid);

           // Create the followup activity
           CRMService.Create(followup);
```

Comment: Thanks, this creates a task entity and attaches it with a lead using 'regardingobjectid' attribute, but i am unable find a 'salesliterature' entity (activity) in microsoft docs that can be associated with a lead in the same way.

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider thats right, in my first answer line I said - this is not something OOB, probably a custom activity in your environment

Answer (score 0):

this error show to you that your relation name is wrong so you should find correct relation name.so you need to go CRM customization and under the SalesLiterature entity in relationships find correct schema name